# counting records on the same table with different values possibly none sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a inventory table with a condition i.e. new, used, other, and i am query a small set of this data, and there is a possibility that all the record set contains only 1 or all the conditions.  I tried using a case statement, but if one of the conditions isn't found nothing for that condition returned, and I need it to return 0

This is what I've tried so far:

```
select(
case
    when new_used = 'N' then 'new'
    when new_used = 'U' then 'used'
    when new_used = 'O' then 'other'
    end
    )as conditions,
    count(*) as count
from myDB
where something = something
group by(
case 
    when New_Used = 'N' then 'new'
    when New_Used = 'U' then 'used'
    when New_Used = 'O' then 'other'
end
)
```

This returns the data like:

```
conditions | count
------------------
new           10
used          45
```

I am trying to get the data to return like the following:

```
conditions | count
------------------
new        | 10
used       | 45
other      | 0
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH constants(letter,word) AS 
(
  SELECT l,w FROM (VALUES('N','new'),('U','used'),('O','other')) AS x(l,w)
)
SELECT 
  conditions = c.word, 
  [count] = COUNT(x.new_used)
FROM constants AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.myDB AS x
ON c.letter = x.new_used
AND something = something
GROUP BY c.word;
```

Comment: works like a charm.  Could you explain the "WITH (...) portion?

Comment: It's called a [common table expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx). Not necessary in this case, I just prefer it to a derived table approach (which is what Mike used in his answer).

Comment: You might also be interested in the article about [Using Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx). I've found it useful in addition to the CTE article Aaron referenced in his comment.

Comment: I've used them or even heard about them.  They could come in handy in certain instances.  I've learned something new today.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try this -

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (new_used CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO @t (new_used)
  SELECT t = 'N'
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'N'
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'U'

SELECT conditions, ISNULL(r.cnt, 0) AS [count]
FROM (
    VALUES('U', 'used'), ('N', 'new'), ('O', 'other')
) t(c, conditions)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT new_used, COUNT(1) AS cnt
    FROM @t
    --WHERE something = something
    GROUP BY new_used
) r ON r.new_used = t.c
```

in output -

```
new     2
used    1
other   0
```

Comment: No problem, simple typo that's all. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as a cross-tab:

```
select
sum(case when new_used = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) as N,
sum(case when new_used = 'U' then 1 else 0 end) as U,
sum(case when new_used = 'O' then 1 else 0 end) as Other
from myDB
where something = something
```

Comment: Of course without pivoting this produces the output "on its side" - e.g. a column for each condition, instead of a row for each condition.